# how can i improve bulk calculation from file data

Tags: python-2.7, math

I have a file of binary values.  The section I am looking at is 4 byte int with the values in the pattern of `MW1, MVAR1, MW2, MVAR2,...`

I read the values in with

```
temp = array.array("f")
temp.fromfile(file, length *2)
mw_mvar = temp.tolist()
```

I then calculate the magnitude like this.

```
mag = [0] * length
for x in range(0,length * 2, 2):
    a = mw_mvar[x]
    b = mw_mvar[x + 1]
    mag[(x / 2)] = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
```

The calculations (not the read) are doubling the total length of my script.  I know there is (theoretically) a way to do this faster because am mimicking a script that ultimately calls fortran (pyd to call function dlls in fortran i think) which is able to do this calculation with negligible affect on run time.

This is the best i can come up with.  any suggestions for improvements?

I have also tried `math.pow()`, `**.5`, `**2` with no differences.

Comment: Your snippets are not complete, as you leave out the definitions of some terms, such as `thermal_mva_results_base`. Your explanation of file `f` is also weak. Please give a fuller example of the file, a statement of the file's usual length, and a complete code snippet. The types of the variables and the data matters for your question.

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry that was a typo.  i simplified the names for the post and didnt change that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with no luck improving the calculations, I went around the problem.  I realised that I only needed 1% of those calculated values so I created a class to calculate them on demand.  It was important (to me) that the resulting code act similar to as if it were a list of calculated values.  A lot of the remainder of the process uses the values and different versions of the data are pre-calculated.  The class means i don't need a set of procedures for each version of data

```
class mag:
    def __init__(self,mw_mvar):
        self._mw_mvar = mw_mvar
        #_sgn = sgn
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._mw_mvar/2)
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return sqrt(self._mw_mvar[2*item] ** 2 + self._mw_mvar[2*item+1] ** 2)
```

ps this could also be done in a function and take both versions.  i would have had to make more changes to the overall script.

```
function (a,b,x): 
    if b[x]==0:
        return a[x]
    else: 
        return sqrt(a[x]**2 + b[x]**2)
```